# how to include or exclude attributes while mapping in orika mapper?

Tags: orika

I am using Orika Mapper.
I want to know that can I **include or exclude the attributes** while mapping using Orika Mapper.
If it is possible then how to do the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can include attributes simply by defining the mapping.
Have a look at the [User Guide](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/mappings-via-classmapbuilder.html).

You can use `byDefault()` to automatically map fields with the same names, explicitly define two-way mappings using `field("fieldA", "fieldB")` or one-way mappings using `fieldAtoB("fieldA", "fieldB")` and `fieldBtoA("fieldB", "fieldA")`.

If you want to explicitly exclude a field from mapping (eg. when using `byDefault()`), you can use `exclude("field")`. You can chain `.exclude("field1").exclude("field2").exclude("field3")` multiple times to exclude multiple fields.

Comment: Firstly thanx for your response.
In your case, for mapping i already know which fields i have to include or exclude.
I am passing list of attributes dynamically which i want to include or exclude. I want to know how to do it dynamically.

Comment: Suppose i have 2 entities i.e., Entity A and Entity B.
At runtime i want to pass the Entity name for which i want to map, and also the attributes which are excluded during mapping.

Comment: The typical use case of Orika is that you declare the mappings statically, when configuring the MapperFactory and then you only ask the mapperFactory for a relevant mapper. However, if you want to register class maps dynamically, you still can do it: `mapperFactory.classMap(A.class, B.class).field("fieldA", "fieldB").exclude("commonField").byDefault().register()`. You just need to provide the A/B types and field names dynamically.

Comment: Can you please let me know, how to exclude list of fields(mentioning more than one field name in exclude method)?